# Using svyglm within plyr call

Tags: r, plyr

This is clearly something idiosyncratic to R's [survey package](http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/). I'm trying to use `llply`  from the [plyr package](http://plyr.had.co.nz) to make a list of `svyglm` models. Here's an example:

```
library(survey)
library(plyr)

foo <- data.frame(y1 = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob=.25),
                  y2 = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob=.5),
                  y3 = rbinom(50, size = 1, prob=.75),
                  x1 = rnorm(50, 0, 2),
                  x2 = rnorm(50, 0, 2),
                  x3 = rnorm(50, 0, 2),
                  weights = runif(50, .5, 1.5))
```

My list of dependent variables' column numbers

```
dvnum <- 1:3
```

Indicating no clusters or strata in this sample

```
wd <- svydesign(ids= ~0, strata= NULL, weights= ~weights, data = foo)
```

A single svyglm call works

```
svyglm(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3, design= wd)
```

And `llply` will make a list of base R `glm` models

```
llply(dvnum, function(i) glm(foo[,i] ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = foo))
```

But `llply` throws the following error when I try to adapt this method to `svyglm`

```
llply(dvnum, function(i) svyglm(foo[,i] ~ x1 + x2 + x3, design= wd))

Error in svyglm.survey.design(foo[, i] ~ x1 + x2 + x3, design = wd) : 
all variables must be in design= argument
```

So my question is: how do I use `llply` and `svyglm`?

Comment: You may need to run this with a loop that creates a proper formula object for each model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DWin was on to something with his comment about correct formula.

`reformulate` will do this.

```
dvnum <- names(foo)[1:3]

llply(dvnum, function(i) {
    svyglm(reformulate(c('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),response = i), design = wd)})
```